# How to fix ' Argument list too long' error?

Tags: bash, perl, shell

ive executed this command to delete all occurrences of "#" from a huge amount of files (about 3000)in folder train,

```
perl -pi -e "s/#//g" /Users/Kian/Desktop/Acsegment/espslabs/train/*
```

but I got this error: `/bin/bash: /usr/bin/perl: Argument list too long`

Can anyone suggest a way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leave globing to perl instead of bash which has limitations,

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{ @ARGV = glob(pop) } s/#//g' "/Users/Kian/Desktop/Acsegment/espslabs/train/*"
```

or when are spaces in globed directory,

```
perl -MFile::Glob=bsd_glob -pi -e 'BEGIN{ @ARGV = bsd_glob(pop) } s/#//g' "/Users/Kian/Desktop/Acsegment/espslabs/train/*"
```

Comment: Thank you for respond Сухой27, I tried your solution, but I receive again the same error.

Comment: Both work for me.  Also (in case anyone shares an initial misconception of mine) I wondered if `"files*"` was getting expanded by the shell instead of `perl` and needed to be changed to single-quotes.  I was wrong though: `echo "*"` and `echo '*'` behave the same, and neither is expanded by the shell like `echo *`.  (This also checks out with `print $#ARGV` in perl)

Answer (score 7):

That's what `xargs` is all about.

```
ls /Users/Kian/Desktop/Acsegment/espslabs/train |
   xargs perl -i -pe's/#//g'
```

`find` can do it too, and it allows you to select which files to modify much more flexibly.

```
find /Users/Kian/Desktop/Acsegment/espslabs/train \
   -type f -maxdepth 1 \
   -exec perl -i -pe's/#//g' {} +
```

Of course, you could also generate the file list in Perl.

```
perl -i -pe'BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV } s/#//g' \
    '/Users/Kian/Desktop/Acsegment/espslabs/train/*'
```

But you have to escape spaces in the path unless you use `bsd_glob`.

```
perl -i -pe'
   use File::Glob qw( bsd_glob );
   BEGIN { @ARGV = map bsd_glob($_), @ARGV }
   s/#//g
' '/Users/Kian/Desktop/Acsegment/espslabs/train/*'
```