# How do you use globbing in perl for a one-liner with many files, avoiding xargs/find/etc

Tags: shell, perl, glob

When there are too many matching files, shells like `bash` break if you include a glob pattern on the commandline like

```
perl -pi -e 's/hi/bye/' too_many_files*
```

You can work around this with `xargs`, gnu `parallel`, or `find`, but for complex commands, these can be difficult to get right in terms of quoting, and they can also be less efficient than running `perl` once.

Is there a way to use `perl`'s built-in globbing support for something like this? (which does not work)

```
perl -pi -e 's/hi/bye/' 'manyfiles*' # <-- Does not work.
```

Comment: What is the actual pattern to build the filelist? ... Must it be a a glob?

Comment: Note this isn't a `bash` problem, but an issue for operating systems that don't allow arbitrarily long command lines.

Comment: "difficult to get right in terms of quoting" -- what do you mean? xargs doesn't require changes in quoting. In `printf '%s\0' too_many_files* | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/hi/bye/'`, the perl command is quoted exactly the same way as your original code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not able to reconstruct a good example right now, though I believe I've run into problems, perhaps with nesting of different kinds of quotes, where the single perl command works on one file, but not when called from outside like this.  `parallel -q` has sometimes been handy, and sometimes insufficient.

Comment: `parallel` tries to be "smart" in ways that make quoting difficult. I strongly advise against its use. For background, the thread at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html, and the [unix.se] question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349483/why-doesnt-gnu-parallel-work-with-bash-c are good places to start. xargs is much less clever, does fewer things behind your back, and generally leans towards making only easily-foreseeable kinds of trouble.

Comment: Re "*these can be difficult to get right in terms of quoting*", huh? not at all

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have indeed been assuming that parallel and xargs would have similar issues, so I'll look into your suggestions.  I'm still very glad to have learned the BEGIN/glob trick, though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942616/411282), you can use a `BEGIN` block to have `perl` (rather than the shell) expand the file list:

slightly modified from the original:

> Leave globing to perl instead of bash which has limitations,
>
> ```
> perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{ @ARGV = glob(pop) } s/#//g' "*"
> ```
>
> or when there are spaces in globed directory,
>
> ```
> perl -MFile::Glob=bsd_glob -pi -e 'BEGIN{ @ARGV = bsd_glob(pop) } s/#//g' "*"
> ```

For more about `glob` vs `bsd_glob`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262481/411282).

(This is intentionally duplicated as I had trouble finding the answer quickly with search terms I had in mind.)

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple to use Perl's [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) for the filelist and then process files

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -we'path($_)->edit_lines( sub { s/hi/bye/ } ) for glob "files*"'
```

Here I use [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path%3A%3ATiny) with its `edit_lines` (see `edit`) while there are yet other tools for this.

A call to `glob` in the list context<sup>†</sup> returns a list and we iterate over it, editing the file in a single statement.  If there is more to do, or you'd rather open a file by hand and go through lines, then can put that code in a `do` block

```
perl -wE'do { ...process file... } for glob "files*"'
```

It there are so many files that the shell has a problem with the list then you may want to avoid building it in Perl as well, which is what `glob` does in list context. (Even as there is no limit, nor a disastrous performance impact.)

There's a number of ways to take those files one by one -- using [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find), or things like `readdir` in scalar context or [Path::Tiny::iterator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path%3A%3ATiny#iterator).  This requires selection of entries they find by regex so a "translation" of the glob, but that shouldn't be a problem given how simple glob patterns are.  Or use `glob` in scalar context.<sup>†</sup>

If there may be spaces in entry names use [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob) -- merely adding `use File::Glob qw(:bsd_glob);` to the program will use that instead of `glob`.  With a one-liner one can do

```
perl -MFile::Glob=":bsd_glob" -wE'...'
```

In this case you can also suppress sorting that `glob` does by using `GLOB_NOSORT` flag, good to do for large filelists unless you need them sorted. Then we have to actually replace `glob`

```
perl -MFile::Glob=":bsd_glob" -wE'do { ... } for bsd_glob("files*", GLOB_NOSORT)'
```

Tools other than `glob`, like ones mentioned above, don't care about spaces in names.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Another way is to use `glob` in the scalar context, when it acts as an iterator, and process each file as it is returned

```
perl -wE'do { ... } while "files*"'
```

(Or `while (glob "files*") { ... }`)

This avoids building the potentially huge list upfront.

Comment: If using `File::Glob` directly, might as well also tell it not to sort the files (Unless you really want them sorted, of course) to save some work.

Comment: @Shawn  Indeed, a good point to avoid sorting on large filelists, thank you. Edited..

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to your claims, `find` and/or `xargs` doesn't require any special or complex quoting. And contrary to your claims, it doesn't have to be inefficient either.

Here are some ways to use `find` and/or `xargs`:

```bash
find -maxdepth 1 -name 'too_many_files*' -exec               perl -pe'...' -i~ {} +
find -maxdepth 1 -name 'too_many_files*' -exec               perl -pe'...' -i~ {} \;
find -maxdepth 1 -name 'too_many_files*'         | xargs -r  perl -pe'...' -i~
find -maxdepth 1 -name 'too_many_files*' -print0 | xargs -r0 perl -pe'...' -i~
```

The first requires GNU `find`.

The second calls launches a new `perl` process for each file, so it's slower than the others which launch `perl` the minimum number of times.

The third doesn't support line feeds in the file names.

---

That said, you could also use

```bash
perl -MFile::Glob=bsd_glob -pe'
   BEGIN { @ARGV = map bsd_glob($_), @ARGV }
   s/hi/bye/;
' 'too_many_files*'
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can work around this with xargs, gnu parallel, or find, but for complex commands, these can be difficult to get right in terms of quoting

Yep. GNU Parallel provides `--shellquote` to help with quoting:

```
$ parallel --shellquote
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. You are either an expert
parallel: Warning: (in which case: YOU ARE AWESOME!) or maybe you forgot
parallel: Warning: ::: or :::: or -a or to pipe data into parallel. If so
parallel: Warning: consider going through the tutorial: man parallel_tutorial
parallel: Warning: Press CTRL-D to exit.
perl -pi -e 's/"Hi Joe"/"Bye \$\$\$"/'  <-- pasted
'perl -pi -e '"'"'s/"Hi Joe"/"Bye \$\$\$"/'"'"
<CTRL-D>
```

You can then use:

```
ls | parallel 'perl -pi -e '"'"'s/"Hi Joe"/"Bye \$\$\$"/'"'"
```

But that is not very readable.

Instead I recommend defining a bash function. It improves readability greatly - especially if the code is bigger than a one-liner:

```
doit() {
  perl -pi -e 's/"Hi Joe"/"Bye \$\$\$"/' "$1"
  # do other stuff
}
export -f doit

ls | parallel doit
```